# Audio toca em editor, mas não no celular

Tags: c#, mobile, unity-5

Estou fazendo um jogo narrado para Android em unity 5 com c#, uso a seguinte função para pegar o áudio da voz da google.
Porém ele funciona somente no editor, quando eu tenho ele instalado no celular o áudio não toca, verifiquei se o aparelho tem som, aumentei o volume, tentei em outros aparelhos e sempre a mesma coisa.

```
public AudioSource _audio;
public string textoATocar;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
   _audio = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
}

public void tocaIsso( string audioTocar){
   StartCoroutine( DownloadAudio( audioTocar ) );
}

IEnumerator DownloadAudio( string textoATocar2 ){
   string url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&textlen=32&client=tw-ob&q=" + textoATocar2 + "&tl=Pt-gb";
   WWW www = new WWW(url);
   yield return www;

   _audio.clip = www.GetAudioClip( false, true, AudioType.MPEG );
   _audio.Play();
}
```

Ps: faço a chamada da função assim, `textAudio.tocaIsso(opcoesMenu[ posicaoMenu ]);`, que serve para narrar o menu.

Edit: Eu atualizei o meu unity pra ultima versão e agora aparece um erro,

```
Error: Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for resource Ȯ1C, (Operation could not be performed because specified sound/DSP connection is not ready. )
UnityEngine.WWWAudioExtensions:GetAudioClip(WWW, Boolean, Boolean, AudioType)
<DownloadAudio>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/TextoToAudio.cs:27)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

mas já procurei por tudo, e não achei um jeito de contornar isso.

Comment: Pode ser o formato do audio, lembro que alguns formatos não eram reproduzidos no celular por ele não ter suporte.

Comment: Também pensei isso, mas o áudio é em MP3, e o celular toca outros arquivos mp3 normalmente.

Comment: Eu tentaria um `WAV` se fosse você, lembre que o player que reproduz os sons do sistema é diferente.

Comment: Então, ai tem o problema que eu to usando esse link para pegar o audio  " http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&textlen=32&client=tw-ob&q=" + textoATocar2 + "&tl=Pt-gb ", que eu preciso de um áudio variável, que eu pego pelo google, que só fornece em mp3

Answer (score 0):

Eu descobri que esse é um bug da própria engine, e até o momento 30/10/2017 ele não foi corrigido, mas ele acontece em stream de áudio.